# Dell OptiPlex 755 Hex Code on BIOS Launch?

Tags: bios, post, dell-optiplex

We have a Dell Optiplex 755 which is freezing at POST and displaying what appears to be a hexadecimal string in the top-left corner of the screen, like so:

[image: 6a3e100a6a3e100a6a3e100a]

Any ideas on what is causing this?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest looking at the Dell website and/or contacting Dell support.